# Delivering a payload to a URL, using cURL

Tags: bash, git, curl

I need help figuring out the cURL request required to send the following data to a URL.

```
{"requestid":"555555", 
"partnermatchid":"10000-000-0000-0000-000", 
"usercontext":{"ipaddressmasked":"XXX.XXX.X.XXX", 
"useragent":"mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit/537.10 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/28.0.1500.95 safari/537.36", 
"country":"us"}, 
"pagecontext":{"pagetypeid":"2","numslots":"3"}, 
"istest":false}
```

My main issue is that I can't figure out how to format the payload above to be sent properly to a URL. So far, I have been utilizing the `-d` and `-X POST` commands. I am using Git Bash.

I appreciate your help and input.

Comment: Can you explain *why* it isn't working? Is the format wrong, or is the command itself failing, or is the server rejecting your input for some weird reason, or...?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
echo '{"requestid":"555555", 
"partnermatchid":"10000-000-0000-0000-000", 
"usercontext":{"ipaddressmasked":"XXX.XXX.X.XXX", 
"useragent":"mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit/537.10 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/28.0.1500.95 safari/537.36", 
"country":"us"}, 
"pagecontext":{"pagetypeid":"2","numslots":"3"}, 
"istest":false}' | curl --data-binary @- -H "Content-Type: text/json" <URL>
```

The interesting parts:

- The `echo` at the beginning is just to get the body content into pipe to `curl`. Note the use of single-quotes to prevent bash from interpreting any of the quotation marks or anything in the JSON.
- The use of `--data-binary` is to tell `curl` to send the body exactly as-is, unmodified. The `@-` part tells it to read from stdin (in this case, the pipe from `echo`.
- The `-H "Content-Type: text/json" might not be needed, but servers often get grumpy if there's a request body and the content-type isn't specified.
- I did *not* include a `User-Agent` header. You have a UA string in the JSON, so hopefully the server isn't going to be picky about the UA header, but you can easily override `curl`'s default UA string if you want to.
- `<URL>` is, of course, the URP that you want to send your POST to. Note that if it's an HTTPS URL and the certificate isn't trusted by `curl`, you'll need to tell `curl` to use insecure mode (`-k` flag).